# Referrals websites

Tags: google-analytics

I'm using google analytics's, but I really can't manage to view referring websites (website url's where users are coming to my website from) I can check it only while checking real time stats.

I have been googling, but couldn't find proper solution, will be grateful if someone can tell me which options should I enable, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going to `standard reporting > traffic sources > Sources > referrals`

Comment: Grrr, how could I miss it, indeed your are right, thank you!

Comment: @Matim quite easy to miss, te GA menu is pretty unintuitive.

Comment: Yeap thats right, I was quite disappointed, before using google sites and google analytics's I thought they will be perfects since they are from google, but what ever, nothing is perfect unfortunately.